# Get the last used credit card with stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

As you know, Stripe saves all used credit cards of a given customer, and you can access all the credit cards information via the API:

```
{
  object: "list",
  url: "/v1/customers/cu_15rCFB2eZvKYlo2CnkaAKSFt/sources",
  has_more: false,
  data: [
    <Card card id=card_15rCuj2eZvKYlo2CwY0fBAf3 at 0x00000a> JSON: {
      "id": "card_15rCuj2eZvKYlo2CwY0fBAf3",
      "object": "card",
      "last4": "4242",
      "brand": "Visa",
      "funding": "credit",
      "exp_month": 10,
      "exp_year": 2018,
      "country": "US",
      "name": "aysfzai@hotmail.com",
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "address_city": null,
      "address_state": null,
      "address_zip": null,
      "address_country": null,
      "cvc_check": "pass",
      "address_line1_check": null,
      "address_zip_check": null,
      "dynamic_last4": null,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "customer": "cus_63Iq2Qa90oQrmv"
    },
    <stripe.Card[...] ...>,
    <stripe.Card[...] ...>
  ]
}
```

My questions are :

1. how are these data ordered ?
2. How can I get the last Credit card? is it the first element of the json response or the last ?

If anyone has any idea, I would be thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about fetching this data of customer??

If so then:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( {stripe_secret_key} );
\Stripe\Customer::retrieve( {customer_id} );
```

For using above code you need to include the latest library of [Stripe.](https://stripe.com)